# What date format to use in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm using `moment.js` to get a UTC date offset.

I have the following code, which gives me the offset, but I get the warning `"Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date"`.

```
var s = booking.booking_date_time.toString();
console.log(moment(s).parseZone(s).utcOffset());
```

The `s` variable above is set to `"Mon Jun 13 2016 08:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)"`.

I know that to get ride of the warning, I need to specify the date format in moment, but I'm not sure what the date format should be. I've tried this format `"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: How about taking the opposite approach, formatting the *current* time until it looks close enough to the format of your input?

Comment: Is `booking.booking_date_time` a `Date` object? If so, just pass it in to moment directly.  There's no need to go through strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):-

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, then fall back to new Date(string) if a known format is not found.

So I suggest you to use `moment(new Date(booking.booking_date_time))`, which will work. (**If `booking.booking_date_time` is a valid date object**)

Also refer [moment-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) to change to different formats supported by `moment.js`

Comment: Parsing dates via the `Date` object is unreliable, and the suggested approach is to also pass in the format 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ', as Maggie suggested below. More info on the `Date` parsing inconsistencies [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407#issuecomment-155630060).

Comment: @AngelaNicholas Why parsing dates via the Date object is unreliable?

Comment: the explanation is in the hyperlink above (https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407#issuecomment-155630060); here's the relevant quote -- "Parsing dates via the Date object is unreliable and inconsistent across platforms. There are different implementations and different behaviors. Sometimes you may get local time. Sometimes you may get UTC. Sometimes you may get Invalid Date. Sometimes you will get different results near DST transitions. Don't try to defeat the error. Instead, follow our guidelines. Either use a known format or supply a format string."

Answer (score 2):

Moment uses it's own parse token set that is not the same as other libraries. As such, you have some wrong tokens here. In addition, you need to specify that GMT is in the string, but escape it with [].

All summed up:

```
moment('Mon Jun 13 2016 08:00:00 GMT+1000', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ').format()
"2016-06-12T17:00:00-05:00"
```

Note that when you parse using the default moment constructor, it will convert from the specified offset to the user's local time.

If you want to keep a fixed offset, use parseZone:

```
moment.parseZone('Mon Jun 13 2016 08:00:00 GMT+1000', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ').format()
"2016-06-13T08:00:00+10:00"
```

Edit: Pay attention to the comment. If it's a date, just pass it in directly. I should have noticed that.